# My iOS device not appearing in xcode device list, showing in organizer

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, device

I m having xcode 4.5,

I have connected my iTouch(registered in developer program) to Mac Machine. It is appearing in Organizer's Device list. But, it is not appearing in xcode's device list(where simulators are) in one of my project. It is also shown when i open my other proejects.

So, What may be the problem in my this project, in which device is not appearing. Is any settings should be changed??

Comment: open organiser in xcode,under device section you will find the **reason for device not connecting.**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See the image below and change the settings.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You might need to "trust" the computer - a device will not show up in the organizer if the computer is not trusted.

Restart the iPad while it is connected to the computer. When it restarts, it will ask if you want to "Trust" the computer or not.  Do so, then the device will show up in the Xcode Organizer.

Answer (score 7):

1. Restart XCode
2. Try Changing the USB Port.
3. Clean Project. `Shift + command + K`.
4. Clear Derive Data.

Answer (score 7):

For me, the solution was to disconnect ExpressVPN (not sure why this would impact my device showing up)

Comment: Ditto, except in my case it was NordVPN I needed to disconnect. I've come to expect it to frequently stop my internet for no explicable reason but never expected it to prevent my iPhone from showing in Xcode :/

Comment: I also had to disconnect the Cisco AnyConnect VPN so my iPhone can be shown

Answer (score 6):

I tried everything and then found that my device was identified on a different Mac but not mine. Quit and Reopen XCode resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

The deployment target for your project is probably too high (e.g. iOS 7 if you are using Xcode 5 DP). Change it to a minimum version compatible with your device and try again.

Answer (score 3):

Go to organiser, select your device, click on remove button at bottom of organiser screen, unplug your device and connect it once again. That's it. your device should be appear in xcode.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Reboot the Mac]

The first thing you should try is to Reboot your Mac, solves most of the hardware problems!! :D

Answer (score 2):

I’m using a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) and my iPhone was connected through a USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter. The iPhone was no longer shown as a connected device. Tried connecting the iPhone directly to the MacBook without the Adapter and now it IS a connected device. I’m going to consider using a wireless connection for development.

Comment: Same here. I have two thunderbolt -> USB-A adapters. In one of them, the iPhone does not show, and using the second one it works (two different brands).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it by going into `Settings > Developer > Clear Trusted Computers` then unplugging and plugging in my iPhone and clicking `Trust` in the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Go to organiser and click your device in the left panel. On the right, see if it is registered for development or not. If not, click "Use for development".
Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 1):

Got this problem too. I plug my phone to Apple Cinema Display. Turns out I **forgot to plug in the display's USB cable to my MacBook Air**, so only power goes to my device but no data transmission (/me facepalm big time).

Answer (score 1):

My case, I was trying to run a sample app I just downloaded and didn't knew it was iPad only. And I had plugged-in an iPhone. :)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above helped me. But what helped me was opening the `Devices & Simulators` window in Xcode, which then showed me my iPhone and started downloading symbols:

[image]

[image]

Comment: my device is showing here but invisible outside next to the scheme name ...