# Xcode will not connect to iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, cordova

Xcode won't connect to my ipad it says:

```
"To use this device with Xcode, unlock the device and choose "Trust"."
```

I have done that. Is there any chance that setting up trust will not work? How do I get this to connect?

I am using cordova, if that helps anyone.

Comment: If you reconnect your device? http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5868 What's happening?

Comment: Same thing, I work on a team with multiple devices, and when plugging in any of them, this still happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like this problem is the same one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331741/my-ios-device-not-appearing-in-xcode-device-list-showing-in-organizer)

It looks like you may need to go into the "TARGETS" of the app into the summary and "iOS Application Target" and change the "Deployment Target" according to the iOS version of your iPad.

Also if that doesn't work then another person suggests restarting your ipad while connected to your computer then hit "trust" again when it pops up.

Comment: That did it, I had to change the 'iOS Deployment Target' field, for some reason, it was pointing to 7.0, and not 7.1.

Comment: I had to restart the iPad while connected at which point Xcode reprocessed symbol files and then everything worked like normal

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After restarting the Ipad everything worked fine

Comment: same here, first ipad worked fine, then plugged in a second and i guess the mac got confused.  only restarting the tablet fixed the issue, restarting xcode did nothing.